# How do you use play scala specs2 matchers across multiple files

Tags: scala, playframework, specs2

I am using Play 2.2.1 with scala and trying to test with Specs2 matchers across multiple files.  Everything works fine in one very large ApplicationSpec.scala file but I would like to move the code to separate files.

The following code is what I am using to test across multiple files but it is very intermittent.

**ApplicationSpec.scala file**

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.matcher.JsonMatchers
import org.specs2.runner._
import org.junit.runner._

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ApplicationSpec extends PlaySpecification with JsonMatchers {
    "Test using another file" should {

        testing

        "End of test" in {"End" must beEqualTo("End")}        
    }
```

**This function is located inside the ApplicationSpec.scala file**

```
def testing() {

    "Multiple files" should {

        "Testing testFile1" in {

            testFile1.test1
            testFile1.test2

            "Test1 and Test2 should print before this line" in { 1 must beEqualTo(1)}

       }

        "Testing testFile2" in {

            testFile2.test3
            testFile2.test4

            "Test3 and Test4 should print before this line" in { 1 must beEqualTo(1)}

        }
    }
}
```

**testFile1.scala**

```
object testFile1 extends ApplicationSpec {

def test1 {     
    "testFile1 - test1" in {1 must beEqualTo(1)}          
}

def test2 {     
    "testFile1 - test2" in {1 must beEqualTo(1)}          
}

}
```

**testFile2.scala**

```
object testFile2 extends ApplicationSpec {

def test3 {   
    "testFile2 - test3" in {1 must beEqualTo(1)}      
}

def test4 {     
    "testFile2 - tes4" in {1 must beEqualTo(1)}       
}

}
```

**Test results**  Each time "play test" is run test1, test2, and test3, test4 may or may not print out.  Sometimes all four tests show up or none of the tests are printed.

```
+ test WS logic
[info] 
[info]   Test using another file should
[info] 
[info]     Multiple files should
[info] 
[info]       Testing testFile1
[info]       + Test1 and Test2 should print before this line
[info] 
[info]       Testing testFile2
[info]       + testFile2 - test3
[info]       + testFile2 - tes4
[info]       + Test3 and Test4 should print before this line
[info]   + End of test
[info] 
[info] Total for specification testFile2
[info] Finished in 1 second, 713 ms
[info] 6 examples, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] testFile1
[info] 
[info] Application should
[info] + test WS logic
[info] 
[info]   Test using another file should
[info] 
[info]     Multiple files should
[info] 
[info]       Testing testFile1
[info]       + testFile1 - test1
[info]       + testFile1 - test2
[info]       + Test1 and Test2 should print before this line
[info] 
[info]       Testing testFile2
[info]       + Test3 and Test4 should print before this line
[info]   + End of test
[info] 
[info] Total for specification testFile1
[info] Finished in 111 ms
[info] 6 examples, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] ApplicationSpec
[info] 
[info] Application should
[info] + test WS logic
[info] 
[info]   Test using another file should
[info] 
[info]     Multiple files should
[info] 
[info]       Testing testFile1
[info]       + Test1 and Test2 should print before this line
[info] 
[info]       Testing testFile2
[info]       + Test3 and Test4 should print before this line
[info]   + End of test
[info] 
[info] Total for specification ApplicationSpec
[info] Finished in 99 ms
[info] 4 examples, 0 failure, 0 error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use traits to declare examples then import them to the main specification by mixing them in:

```
class TestSpec extends org.specs2.mutable.Specification with testFile1 with testFile2 {

  "Test using another file" should {
    testing
    "End of test" in {"End" must beEqualTo("End")}
  }

  def testing {
    "Multiple files" should {
      "Testing testFile1" in {
        tests1
        "Test1 and Test2 should print before this line" in { 1 must beEqualTo(1)}
      }
      "Testing testFile2" in {
        tests2
        "Test3 and Test4 should print before this line" in { 1 must beEqualTo(1)}
      }
   }
}

trait testFile1 extends org.specs2.mutable.Specification {
  def tests1 = {
    "testFile1 - test1" in {1 must beEqualTo(1)}
    "testFile1 - test2" in {1 must beEqualTo(1)}
  }
}

trait testFile2 extends org.specs2.mutable.Specification {
  def tests2 = {
    "testFile2 - test3" in {1 must beEqualTo(1)}
    "testFile2 - tes4" in {1 must beEqualTo(1)}
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you exclude files from sbt run?  I tried creating another directory with testFile1 and testFile2 in it.  The following command was added to the build.sbt file but is not excluding the files - excludeFilter in unmanagedSources := "tests/*.scala"

Comment: You can add a test filter based on names: `testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Filter(_.startsWith("test")))`

Comment: It is still not working after adding the filter.  On another forum somebody said don't use and file names that start with "test" so I renamed the files. I did an experiment where I created a project with the default tests and added some files.  It ran the test once for each file even though the default test doesn't call any of the files.

Comment: I made a mistake, you need to omit the files starting with `test`: `testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Filter((s: String) => !s.startsWith("test")))`

Comment: With the filter I finally got specs2 to print the results once.  Now the matchers inside the files are not printing but println statements work fine.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't see `testFile1 - test1` or that `1 must beEqualTo(1)` is not being executed?

Comment: I don't see the **testFile1 - test1** when calling testFile1.test1 but println statements before and after work.  Also what is the best way to access test1 from  **inline(testFile1)**

Comment: Do you mind porting this discussion to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/specs2-users?

Comment: It is now working with suggestions from this Google forum [link]https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/specs2-users/Y4suDH4rZuI[link] In the files change **object testFile1** to **trait testFile1** and in the applicationSpec file change the main program to **class TestSpec extends org.specs2.mutable.Specification with testFile1 with testFile2{**